# Python : Save Email Attachment with particular Subject at a given Location

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I want to save attachments from outlook using Python, Attachment from a fixed email subject. I already searched it got an answer that is not working and I cannot comment. - [Save using Win32 Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399835/how-to-save-attachment-from-outlook-using-win32com-client-in-python)

I tried the code and here it is -

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import datetime as date
import os

outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
all_inbox = inbox.Items
val_date = date.date.today()

sub_today = 'Download Attachment 1'
att_today = '1.csv'
for msg in all_inbox:
    if msg.Subject == sub_today:
        break

for att in msg.Attachments:
    if att.FileName == att_today:
        break

att.SaveAsFile(os.getcwd() + '\\1.csv')
att.ExtractFile('1.csv')
open(att)    
att.WriteToFile('x')
```

Upon Executing it in Command Prompt I get error as -

```
D:\r>python attach.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "attach.py", line 21, in <module>
    att.ExtractFile('1.csv')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 527, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: <unknown>.ExtractFile
```

Answer (score 0):

`Attachment` object in OOM (`att` variable in your code) does not expose the ExtractFile method. Neither does it expose the WriteToFile method.

Comment: What should i do to fix

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to do with the saved file.

Comment: I want to perform furthert pandas operations , it is most of the times csv or excel file.

Comment: I really do not know anything about pandas operations. I can only help with the Outlook questions.

Comment: Yes i only need to save email attachment. Ignore pandas

Comment: att.SaveAsFile() line is all you need. Just remove the code below.

Comment: Your help saved the file but the content of the file does'not seems to be ok, anything further that I could do to get the exact attachment saved .

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Please be more specific.

Comment: The code is not working, it reads something, creates a file of the name specified, but the file is not the same attachment in email. Also it takes too much time.

Comment: "Not the same" meaning what? You get a text file while Outlook has an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Kind of yes, I got the same file name, content of file was lost, unreadable characters.

Comment: You really need to post your code. And test your code with text attachments - do they get displayed correctly?